# U(2) versus SU(2), and standard model

Tags: group-theory

I can easily create a function invariant with respect to U(2), but I find myself unable to do the same for SU(2).

---

For U(1):

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a pair of two complex numbers, and let $\mathbf{v}$ be its conjugate transpose. Thus,

$$
\mathbf{v}=\pmatrix{a+ib\\c+id} \\
\mathbf{v}^* = \pmatrix{a-ib & c-id}
$$

I define the function $f(\mathbf{v})$ as

$$
f(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}^*\mathbf{v} \implies f(U\mathbf{v}) = (U\mathbf{v})^* U \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}^*U^*U\mathbf{v}=f(\mathbf{v})\implies U^*U=I
$$

---

But, I cannot wrap my head around a function that is invariant with respect to SU(2) only. I need to somehow inject the definition of the det into the function, such that $g(U\mathbf{v})=T_1(U\mathbf{v})T_2(U\mathbf{v})=g(\mathbf{v})\implies \det(U)=1$. I suspect the simple case to involve the trace, because in the Standard model SU(2) and SU(3) involve the trace of the tensorial product. For instance, the SU(2) is represented as:

$$
Tr (W_{uv}^aW^{uv}_a)
$$

---

Finally,

$$
Tr (W_{uv}^a W^{uv}_a) + B_{uv}B^{uv}
$$

is supposed to be $SU(2)\times U(1)$. Can we show this in terms of injected a transformation $U$ and eliminating it for U(1) and SU(2)?

Comment: What makes you think that there should be a function from $\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C$ invariant with respect to $SU(2)$ but not with respect to $U(2)$?

Comment: I'm just curious about how precisely the function $Tr(W_{uv}^aW^{uv}_a)$ (of the standard model) represents SU(2) and not U(2).

Comment: Hunh... we'll, since I have no idea what those symbols mean, I can't much help. But what you seem to be asking for in the first part of the question is the thing I described in my comment, and I see no a priori reason such a thing should exist. You might want to clarify why that's related to the thing you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this to (1) answer the question asked, and (2) help OP refine the question that seems to really be the source of confusion, which isn't the one asked here. 
$$
\newcommand{\bv} { {\mathbf v }}
\newcommand{\bu} { {\mathbf u }}
\newcommand{\bw} { {\mathbf w }}
\newcommand{\ba} { {\mathbf a }}
\newcommand{\bb} { {\mathbf b }}
\newcommand{\be} { {\mathbf e }}
$$
Let's let $H$ denote $\Bbb C^2$, so I don't have to keep typing that.

Observation 1: For any unit-vector $\bv \in H$, there's a unit vector $\bw \in H$ orthogonal to $\bv$. Reason: $H$ is two dimensional; extend $\bv$ to a basis; then the Gram-Schmidt process lets us find $\bw$.

Let $C(\ba, \bb)$ denote a matrix whose columns are $\ba$ and $\bb$. Then

Observation 2: if $\bv, \bw$ are as in Observation 1, then $C(\bv, \bw)$ is in $U(2)$. Further, it is either also in $SU(2)$, or $C(\bv, -\bw)$ is in $SU(2)$. Reason: definitions of $U(2), SU(2)$, properties of determinant.

Suppose $f: H \to C$ is $U(2)$-invariant, by which OP appears to mean that 
$$
f(Q\bv) = f(\bv)
$$
for any vector $\bv$ and any element $Q \in U(2)$. Then

Observation 3: $f$ is constant on spheres centered at the origin.

Reason: 
Letting $\be = \pmatrix{1\\0}$, let $\bv$ be any unit vector; find $\bw$ an orthogonal unit vector, and consider $A = C(\bv, \bw)$ which, by observation 2, is in $U(2)$. We have $A\be = \bv$, by simple matrix multiplication. So $f(\bv) = f(A \be) = f(\be)$ by equivariance of $f$. That means that for any unit vector $\bv$, we have $f(\bv) = f(\be)$, i.e., $f$ is constant on the unit sphere. I leave the proof for spheres of other radii to you.

Observation 4: with $f$ again $U(2)$-invariant as above, we have that $f$ is $SU(2)$-invariant. Reason: The orbit of $\be$, under $SU(2)$, is still the unit sphere, mimicking the proof in observation 3, although you may need to negate $\bw$ to ensure that $A$ is in $SU(2)$ rather than $U(2)$. To be $SU(2)$ invariant, $f$ need only be constant on orbits...and it is.

In short: a function on $\Bbb C^2$ that's $U(2)$-invariant is **also** $SU(2)$-invariant. So the thing you're looking for doesn't exit.

This *suggests* to me that you don't actually fully understand the meaning of the second thing you claim to be looking for, something to do with standard models. But since I know nothing about that topic, I'll stop here.